# Python Type Hinting After exec() Assignment

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing, pyright

I often have a situation where I make the assignment with exec, like so:

```
 ...
 exec(
     "someClassInstance = someMapper({someInfo})".format(someInfo=someInfo),
     globals(),
 )
```

Where `someClassInfo` is an instance of `SomeClass`.
and then I use `someClassInstance`, like so:

```
...
someVar = someClassInstance.someMethod()  # type: ignore
```

All of that works just fine and I accomplish what I want.

But, from a reading perspective and from the IDE's (in my case, emacs+pyright) perspective, the (non-run-time) type of someClassInstance is not known.

So, I add that "# type: ignore".

But, instead, I want to somehow use python 3's type hinting to make it known that
someClassInstance is of type SomeClass (or one of its ancestors).

Is that possible?

Comment: It would almost certainly be better to *not* use `exec` to create the instance in the first place, even without bringing type-hinting into the mix.

Comment: For example,  'SomeClass' is coming in as a string from the command-line. And it needs to be created with exec. It is not a question of "better to not use".

Comment: You don't need `exec` for this. `someClassInstance = getattr(__main__, cls)()`. Even better, `d = {'SomeClass': SomeClass}; someClassInstance = d[cls]()`.

Comment: If you don't find out the value of `cls` until runtime, you can't provide a *static* type hint for `someClassInstance`.

Comment: I may not know the value of cls until runtime, but I know its ancestors,  and if I knew how, I could provide a static type hint for that ancestor; for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you type

```
cast(type, value1)
```

then the result will be exactly the same as `value`, but you have told the type checker that its type is the indicated type, and that it just has to believe you.

From the documentation:

> `typing.cast(typ, val)`
>
> Cast a value to a type.
>
> This returns the value unchanged. To the type checker this signals
> that the return value has the designated type, but at runtime we
> intentionally don’t check anything (we want this to be as fast as
> possible).

Comment: Back to the example. What we want to cast is ```someClassInstance``` which is assigned with exec.  So, it is undefined.

Comment: If I was to do a ```typing.cast(SomeClass, someClassInstance)``` I would get a "someClassInstance is undefined". You see, the title says: "After exec Assignment".

Comment: After some experimentation, I think there is something that works. I can put a: ```global someClassInstance; someClassInstance = typing.cast(SomeClass, None)``` before the exec() block. But is this the best way?